# Django on a url other than localhost

Tags: python, django, frameworks, server

I have a server aerv.nl.
it has django (a python framework) but when i run the django server it says:
server started at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ how can i let the server run on: http://www.aerv.nl/~filip/ ? (a real url)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to configure your http server and Django. For example if you're using apache you'll need to go through this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

What you're doing here is setting up your server to handle the http requests through your django app.

Comment: I can give a more detailed answer if you could give a little more detail as to your server setup (and provider). E.g. are you using apache, unicorn, nginx, ... and is this hosted on webfaction, linode, ...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to understand how DNS works, then use redirecting and then some proper server (like `nginx` or `apache` with e.g. `gunicorn`), not django development server, which shouldn't be used on production. There is no way you could do what you ask for just with `./manage runserver`. All you can do is to change IP address and port to something different by e.g.: `./manage.py runserver 192.168.0.12:9999` so for example other computers in your network might access your site on this specific IP and port.

## Example

You are owner of domain `example.com`, you have server where you want to server your site with IP address e.g. `5.130.2.19`.
You need go to your domain provider and add an A record which connects these together: `example.com` -> `5.130.2.19`.

Then on your server you set up webserver, e.g. `nginx` and let it run with e.g. this config for your particular server/site:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/example/django/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias   /var/www/example/django/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://upstream_server;
            break;
        }
    }

upstream upstream_server {
  server unix:/var/www/example/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=10s;
}
```

then you would need to run `gunicorn` with something like

```
gunicorn example.wsgi:application --bind=unix:/var/www/example/gunicorn.sock
```

That should be all, but it's of course very brief. Just substitute `example.com` for your URL. It is up to you if this going to be specific record in `nginx` config (think about this as an entry point) or if it is going to be one of route specified in your django project.

### How does it work?

User put `example.com` into an address bar, your computer then ask global DNS servers: *To what IP address example.com points to?*, DNS reply: *It's `5.130.2.19`*. User's browser then sends HTTP request on that IP, where `nginx` get this request and looks inside its config if there is `example.com` *handler*. It find that it is there and that he should look for files in `unix:/var/www/example/gunicorn.sock`. He looks there and see working `gunicorn`, which basically parse python django project to something what `nginx` can present as your website.

Comment: aha! so when i do that but point it to http://aerv.nl/~filip it will work? or do i have to change the HTTPD config?

Comment: It really depends on your configuration as a whole. I update my answer to give you a brief idea.